# Creating Vertical Bar's with divs

Tags: html, css

I'm tring to create two horizontal bars like the below example using only html and css. I'm using the following code:

```
<div style="height: 150px;">
  <div style="width: 55px;float:left;">
      <div>340.8</div>
      <div style="background-color:#95111d; height: 75px;">
          &nbsp;
      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:55px;float:left">
      <div>340.8</div>
      <div style="background-color:#9e9e9e; height: 115px;">
          &nbsp;
      </div>
  </div>
  <br style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

The problem with this is both bars are sitting at the top of their containing div and not at the bottom so you get the 2nd below images effect.

I have some code that will be generating the height of these bars so I can't just add top padding/margin to push them into position. Is there any way to do this without resorting to javascript to calculate a margin and bottom align them?

[image]

[image: End Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the CSS and markup that should do the work (*no `absolute positioning` used*)-

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nj24d/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wraper">
  <div id="c1">
     <div id="h1">340.8</div>
      <div id="b1">
          &nbsp;
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="c2">
      <div id="h2">340.8</div>
      <div id="b2">
          &nbsp;
      </div>
  </div>
  <br style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#wraper {
   height: 150px;
}

#c1 {
   width: 55px;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   display: inline-block;
}

#b1 {
   background-color: #95111d;
   height: 75px;
}

#c2 {
   width: 55px;
   margin-left: -4px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#b2 {
   background-color: #9e9e9e;
   height: 115px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nj24d/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning to fix an element to the bottom of its container.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar">
      <div>
          <div>340.8</div>
          <div style="background-color:#95111d; height: 75px;">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
      <div>
          <div>340.8</div>
          <div style="background-color:#9e9e9e; height: 115px;">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <br style="clear: both" />
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 150px;
}

.bar {
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.bar > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/pAnqe/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired effect by using inline block elements and giving them a vertical-align value of bottom. here is some simple html and css.

html

```
  <span class="bar" style="height:75px;background-color:#95111d;">
      <div class="label">340.8</div>
  </span>
  <span class="bar" style="height:115px;background-color:#9e9e9e;">
      <div class="label">350.1</div>
  </span>
```

css

```
.bar {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 55px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.label {
    position:relative;
    top:-1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div style="height: 150px;position:relative;" >
    <div style="width: 55px;float:left;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0px;">
    <div style="background-color:#95111d; height: 75px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div>340.8</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:55px;float:left;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:55px;">
    <div style="background-color:#9e9e9e; height: 115px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div>340.8</div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both" />
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B44k8/)